# Android get Blob to custom ListView

Tags: java, android

Im getting trouble geting a image from database to put in a custom ListView.

My app dont crash but the image dont apper. And I got that error from the log:

```
 E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /[B@41f754c8: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Sorry for my english, I'll try be clear with my question.

Where is my code:

**DBhelper.java**

That function return me a MatrixCursor with all the data.

```
public MatrixCursor retriveCntDetails() throws SQLException {

        MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "name", "number", "photo"});
        Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + CONTACT_TABLE + "", null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{Long.toString(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(CNT_ID))),
                        cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CNT_NAME)),
                        cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CNT_NUMBER)),
                        cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CNT_PHOTO))
                });
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();

        return mMatrixCursor;
    }
```

**HomeActivity.java**

In that function I fill my custom ListView.

```
public void FillListView() {

        SimpleCursorAdapter adap;

        // Getting reference to listview
        ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

        DBhelper dh = new DBhelper(this);
        dh.open();
        MatrixCursor Mcursor = dh.retriveCntDetails();
        dh.close();

        adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.lv_layout,
                null,
                new String[]{"name", "number", "photo"},
                new int[]{R.id.tv_name, R.id.tv_number, R.id.iv_photo}, 0);


        // Setting the adapter to listview
        lstContacts.setAdapter(adap);

        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
        adap.swapCursor(Mcursor);
    }
```

Comment: please take a look at `SimpleCursorAdapter` source ... by defualt ImageViews(in the row layout) can load only url (if column is string) or load resource by its id (if column is int) ... you need to use custom `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` (it is really easy, you should find some resources by simple googling) ... **edit:** why are you using `MatrixCursor` instead cursor that `mDb.rawQuery` returns?

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for the advice I'll try find something.

Comment: `new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() { @Override public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) { if(view.getId() ==  R.id.iv_photo) { byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex); /* then decode bitmap from "data"(it will be nice to do this on the different thread ... but for test reason you can try without it), cast "view" to ImageView and set bitmap to it */ return true; } return false;/* for other views use default implementation*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Credit to @Selvin for this answer - I'm just going to elaborate a bit to make it clearer for you and future users unfamiliar with Android.*

The [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object, in your example a [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html), is the container for the rows of data. The [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) object, in your example a [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) "binds" these rows/data to views that can then be displayed on-screen. The declaration of your adapter is:

```
adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    getBaseContext(),
    R.layout.lv_layout,
    null,
    new String[]{"name", "number", "photo"},
    new int[]{R.id.tv_name, R.id.tv_number, R.id.iv_photo},
    0
);
```

which means:

> Make an adapter that will use the "lv_layout" for each row. Within
>   each row, bind the value of the "name" column to the view with
>   id "tv_name", the "number" column to the view with id "tv_number" and
>   the "photo" column to the view with id "iv_photo".

Your problem is that it the default way that the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class tries to do this "binding" for `ImageView` instances only works when the value being bound is a URL and not when it's a blob of binary data. That's why you get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, the default adapter is trying to use your blob of data as the URL of an image file.

What you need to do is customise the binding step. To do this, call the [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29) method of your adapter like this:

```
adap.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.iv_photo) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(i);

            Bitmap  bitmap = null;
            // TODO: decode blob data - should be done off UI thread.

            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // Return true to signal that the value was bound to a view 
            // successfully.
            return true;
        } else {
            // Return false for all other views and let the default  
            // binder deal with them.
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

In the above code I haven't covered how to actually do the bitmap decoding. As @Selvin pointed out this should ideally be done off the UI thread. Check out: [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but you can apply that code to my code? Would be more easy to understand becouse I never used that before. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can just copy the whole of the second snippet in my answer after your declaration of `adap`, before `lstContacts.setAdapter(adap);`. But you still need to fill in the `TODO: decode blob data` - I'm not sure how to do that without looking it up.

Comment: Its possivel insert your code when I fill the MatrixCursor?

Comment: I don't understand. Insert my code that starts `adap.setViewBinder(...` after you initialise `adap`. Put it just before the line `lstContacts.setAdapter(adap);`.

Comment: Yeah that is expected. I didn't include the part about decoding the bitmap in my code. I don't know how to do that without looking it up, so I'll leave it to you to work that part out. Check out: [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Comment: thank you very mutch for your help I changed the code and now this works very good. Thanks for the help.